# Cannot exclude hidden table columns from being exported to CSV?

Tags: javascript, html

FIXED!

You are able to export the table by clicking "CSV" button

```js
/*Checkbox To Table Head*/
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
 var apndcss='';
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
 apndcss+=column+"{display:none;}";
 $('#appnedcss').html(apndcss)
    console.log(apndcss);
});

$("#chkbtn").on('change','input',function(){
var apndcss='';
$("#chkbtn input:checkbox").each(function() {
if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name"); 
apndcss+=column+"{display:none;}";
}
})
$('#appnedcss').html(apndcss)
})
});

//Export As CSV 
function download_csv(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    // CSV FILE
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // We have to create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Make sure that the link is not displayed
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to your DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Lanzamos
    downloadLink.click();
}

function export_table_to_csv(html, filename) {
 var csv = [];
 var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
 
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
  
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
            if($(cols[j]).is(':visible')) {
            row.push(cols[j].innerText[0]=='0' ? ("'" + cols[j].innerText) : cols[j].innerText);
        }
  csv.push(row.join(","));  
 }

    // Download CSV
    download_csv(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}

document.querySelector("#CSV").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var html = document.querySelector("table").outerHTML;
 export_table_to_csv(html, "Code_Export.csv");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <style id="appnedcss"></style> 
</head>
<body>

  <body>
 <button class="button button2" id="CSV">CSV</button>
 </br>
 <p id="chkbtn">
  <input type="checkbox" class="theader1" name="theader1" checked="checked"> CODE
  <input type="checkbox" class="theader2" name="theader2"  checked="checked"> DIVISION
  <input type="checkbox" class="theader3" name="theader3" checked="checked"> PROVINCE
  <input type="checkbox" class="theader4" name="theader4" checked="checked"> NAME
 </p>
 </br>
  <table border="1px" id="data">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</th>
   <th class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</th>
   <th class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</th> 
   <th class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</td>
   <td class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</td>
   <td class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</td> 
   <td class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</td>
   <td class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</td>
   <td class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</td> 
   <td class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</td>
   <td class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</td>
   <td class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</td> 
   <td class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</td>
   <td class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</td>
   <td class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</td> 
   <td class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</td>
   <td class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</td>
   <td class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</td> 
   <td class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</td>
   <td class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</td>
   <td class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</td> 
   <td class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</td>
   <td class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</td>
   <td class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</td> 
   <td class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</td>
   <td class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</td>
   <td class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</td> 
   <td class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="theader1" id="theader1">CODE</td>
   <td class="theader2" id="theader2">DIVISION</td>
   <td class="theader3" id="theader3">PROVINCE</td> 
   <td class="theader4" id="theader4">NAME</td>
   </tr>    
   </tbody>
  </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The checkboxes toggle whether or not the columns are visible or not by adding:

```
style="display: none;
```

To every table td.

The problem is that when you press the CSV button ALL the columns are exported.

I want only the visible columns to be exported.

How to do that?

I am assuming an exclude statement based on TD style has to be added somewhere here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
```

I tried implementing the suggestions below:

```
if($(cols[j]).is(':visible') { your push code ...}
```

The actual syntax is:

```
if($(cols[j]).is(':visible')) { your push code ...}
```

I'm not that good at JavaScript, not sure how to implement this.

Comment: still looking for a working demo for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your push, you need a condition to check for the visibility of that cell.

```
if($(cols[j]).is(':visible')) { your push code ...}
```

Comment: Thanks! a working example would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I got it to work the actual syntax was a bit off its this: if($(cols[j]).is(':visible')) { your push code ...}

Comment: Thanks. Missed that bracket.